# How to set the location of junit TemporaryFolder to an environment variable java

Tags: java, junit4

I'm using JUnit's TemporaryFolder class rule to create a temporary folder during JUnit run.

```
@Rule
public final TemporaryFolder folder = new TemporaryFolder(
        new File("C:\\usr")
);
```

The new folder gets created at the path like below

```
C:\usr\junit991415299992369999
```

I'm looking for new folder to be created at the root, for example:

```
C:\usr\
```

Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean `C:\\usr\` to be replaced with new folder?

Comment: I don't want the ' junit991415299992369999 folder' to generate

Comment: The purpose of a temporary file or directory is not to clash with existing files or directories. Think of what would happen if two processes run this unit test at the same time. Why do you want a behavior that contradicts the main purpose of the feature?

Comment: I had this problem: folder path '/usr/' is not a relative path

Comment: So your actual problem is not even remotely connected to what you have posted so far? How about posting the code that produces the error, together with a description of the error? Recommended read: [What is the XY problem?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378)